# Install Alpine Linux without formatting the whole disk

Tags: partitioning, installation, alpine-linux

I'm very new to Linux world, I have tried many Linux distros as Ubuntu, lubuntu, linux mint and finally Alpine Linux that I liked so much after installing it on a vmware virtual machine, and now I want to replace a real machine os previously deployed with lubuntu. The issue is that I have an already partitioned disk (2 TB) and full of data its structure [(Lubuntu partition as /boot)(Swap)(Data partition as /data)], I want just replace lubuntu partition with Alpine installation, I followed this [wiki](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Installing_Alpine_on_HDD_dualbooting#Installing_bootloader_manually) and ended up with boot failure. so how can I make this type of installation.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, [I found a document may help getting the question answered](https://docs.alpinelinux.org/user-handbook/0.1a/Installing/manual.html). It help you make the installation manually, so you will be able to select the target partition for boot and Linux filesystem then you will avoid using the entire hard drive resulting wiping all existing partitions.

Alternatively, you may follow these steps to get things done "without no description, please go to above link for more info.":

1. Boot from Alpine Linux media in any way you like.
2. For login, write 'root' as username
3. Run this command, this step is not in the document above

> apk add parted e2fsprogs grub-efi

4. Partitioning Your Disk as indicated in the link above as per your needs

> YOU HAVE TO REVIEW ABOVE LINK OTHERWISE YOU MAY LOSE YOUR ENTIRE HARD DRIVE

5. Reboot

> Write these commands:

1. Boot from Alpine Linux media in any way you like.
2. For login, write 'root' as username
3. setup-keymap us us
4. setup-hostname alpine

> You can replace 'alpine' with any name you like

6. rc-service hostname restart
7. setup-interfaces -a
8. setup-timezone
9. setup-apkrepos
10. passwd
11. setup-sshd
12. setup-ntp
13. mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
14. mkdir /mnt/boot
15. mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot
16. swapon /dev/sda2
17. You are done, you may reboot to start using your new system.

Comment: You seem to have left out `setup-disk`, so nothing here does the actual setup. See the document you linked.